# Unable to Close files which are read using VBA after the operation

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-formula

Objective: To copy data from all the excel files kept in the folder to the master excel files. The data is being copied correctly. However, I am unable to close all the files which are read by the program. Have tried all these options: `ActiveWorkbook.Close`, `Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False`, `Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False`, but none is working.

How to solve the issue?

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow

    MyFile = Dir("C:\Desktop\Actual Files\")

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0 
        If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If 
        Workbooks.Open (MyFile)   
        Range("A2:O97").Copy   
        Windows("zmaster.xlsm").Activate   
        erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 15))  
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a workbook variable and using this would be a clean way to do it. The aspects within this sub of activating workbooks and interacting with sheets that aren't fully referenced is a concern and you could improve it further by properly referencing these.
Also be careful with `application.screenupdating=false` if you disable it within a sub make sure that every exit point will restore it.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MyFile As String, wbData As Workbook
Dim erow

MyFile = Dir("C:\Desktop\Actual Files\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)

Range("A2:O97").Copy

Windows("zmaster.xlsm").Activate

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 15))

wbData.Close False

MyFile = Dir

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The files are getting closed but since in my each files there are 1152 cells. A dialog box "There is a large amount of information in Clipboard. Click "Yes" for Copying ....etc etc" is appearing each time the file is getting closed after reading. How to solve this? Thanks!